# scale_color_manual not working properly with geom_pointrange ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

scale_color_manual when given colors do not generate the output expected. Minimum reproducible code is provided below:

```r
statsSomeSet <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
 methods    min max mean
<fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
    Method1_LR  40  80  60
    Method2_LR  50  90  70
    Method3_LR  30  70  50
    Method1_RF  50  90  70
    Method2_RF  40  80  60
    Method3_RF  30  70  50
")

statsSomeSet$methods <- factor(statsSomeSet$methods, levels = statsSomeSet$methods)
p <- ggplot(data = statsSomeSet, mapping = aes(x = methods, y = mean)) +
    geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = min, ymax = max)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red", "blue","green", "red", "blue" ))
p + labs(title = "Methods")
```

Comment: Try with mapping a variable on the color aesthetic, e.g. `aes(..., color=methods)`. (;

Comment: @stefan Thank you, that works but why does it give the same color for different names (which is what I wanted anyway). I'm curious how and why it does that. But in the legend 6 different methods are listed

Comment: You have six methods and passed six colors. Hence, by default ggplot2 orders the methods alphabetically and assigns the colors in this order too. There are probably easier ways to achieve the desired result. Instead of passing six colors you could add a column to your df which contains just the name of the Method, i.e. without the suffix an map this column on the color aesthetic. In that case it would be sufficient to pass only three colors to scale_color_manual.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @stefan's comment you can use the `separate` function from `tidyr` to split your methods column into two columns and then map the first to the color aesthetic.

```
library(tidyverse)

statsSomeSet <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
 methods    min max mean
    Method1_LR  40  80  60
    Method2_LR  50  90  70
    Method3_LR  30  70  50
    Method1_RF  50  90  70
    Method2_RF  40  80  60
    Method3_RF  30  70  50
")

statsSomeSet_separated <- statsSomeSet %>%
  separate(methods, c('method_a', 'method_b'), sep="_")

p <- ggplot(data = statsSomeSet_separated, mapping = aes(x = paste(method_a, method_b), y = mean, color = method_a)) +
  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = min, ymax = max))
p + labs(x = 'Methods', title = "Methods")
```

[image]